# BASH. Does not work correctly search and replace of word combination from array in a loop

Tags: bash, shell, search, sed, replace

i want to write script of mass searching and replacing of word combinations using bash.
I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
text="cm punk, dolph ziggler, duke nukem"
IFS=", "
my=( $text )
echo ${my[@]}

text2="the undertaker, john cena, the rock"
IFS=", "
my2=( $text2 )
echo ${my2[@]}

for ((i=0;i<${#my[@]};++i)); do
       sed -i "s/${my[i]}/${my2[i]}/g" text.txt
done
```

For the first look, it works. I saw in a result, script changed word combinations.
But, i decided to see in debug:

```
+ (( i=0 ))
+ (( i<6 ))
+ sed -i s/cm/the/g text.txt
+ (( ++i ))
+ (( i<6 ))
+ sed -i s/punk/undertaker/g text.txt
+ (( ++i ))
+ (( i<6 ))
+ sed -i s/dolph/john/g text.txt
+ (( ++i ))
+ (( i<6 ))
+ sed -i s/ziggler/cena/g text.txt
+ (( ++i ))
+ (( i<6 ))
+ sed -i s/duke/the/g text.txt
+ (( ++i ))
+ (( i<6 ))
+ sed -i s/nukem/rock/g text.txt
+ (( ++i ))
+ (( i<6 ))
```

How you can see, it makes search and replace word by word. But i need swearch and replace word combination. for example, i tried to do it with using only one word combinations in variables (in debug):

```
sed -i 's/cm punk/the undertaker/g' text.txt
```

How you think, where i have error ?

Comment: You're completely on the wrong track. Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand some of the reasons why and then just create a small, clear, robust, portable, efficient awk script to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IFS` variable is not a patter to split string into tokens, but list of characters acting as a separator. So, by setting `IFS=", "` you declare you want to have either comma as space as a token delimiter. So, either you will initialize array directly, like:

```
my=("cm punk", "dolph ziggler", "duke nukem")
```

or modify the `text`/`text2` variables and use sole comma as a separator:

```
text="cm punk,dolph ziggler,duke nukem"
IFS=","
my=( $text )
```